# Join two anonymous tables with each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following query runs:

```
select foo.g from (select 'hello' as g) as foo
```

and this query runs aswell:

```
select bla.x from (select 'world' as x) as bla
```

but this one does not:

```
select * from (select foo.g from (select 'hello' as g) as foo) join (select bla.x from (select 'world' as x) as bla)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.
```

Why is the error ? Is it possible to join these tables somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give names to you tables using `As <temp_table_name>` and you need to specify the *column* two tables are joining `ON`. Since there is no column to join `ON` i used a *tautology* (which will always result `True`) assuming that the result you expect is: *hello* , *world* in two columns

Here is the rearranged query:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select foo.g 
    from 
    (
        select 'hello' as g
    ) as foo
) As t1
inner join 
(
    select bla.x 
    from (select 'world' as x) as bla
) As t2 ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give alias names to your tables. The below code works

```
select * from (select foo.g from (select 'hello' as g) as foo) T1
join (select bla.x from (select 'world' as x) as bla) T2 on t1.g=t2.x
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was due the missing the `ON` keyword.
The `ON` clause works like the `WHERE` clause and is where you add your joining filter.

Its not directly related to the lack of *names* and *aliases* on the tables and columns, but if you don't name your columns and tables the `ON` clause can not know what do you want as result and how do you want to join tables on

Comment: but for example you can do this in postgres: `select * from foo join bar` where foo and bar are tables.

Comment: I lack knowledge on postgres but unique way to join tables without a filter is a cross join (cartesian product between tables rows). That's seems to be it.

Comment: ah i see! so the nomenclature is just different